# Is it safe to delete a functor while calling it?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, undefined-behavior

Let's say I have the following code:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> func_type;

void some_func()
{
  // Irrelevant stuff here. Might take some time...
}

DWORD WINAPI thread_proc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  func_type& func = *static_cast<func_type*>(lpParameter);

  func();

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  HANDLE handle;

  {
    std::function<void ()> my_func(some_func);

    handle = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, &thread_proc, &my_func, 0, NULL);

    // Here we consider my_func won't be destroyed before its operator() is called in the other thread.
    // I know nothing guarantees that, but let's just say it does for this sample.
  }

  ::WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My current implementation seems to work, but this doesn't prove that I'm not facing undefined behavior.

Here my_func **might** be destroyed before the call to its `operator()` returns. But since I'm not refering to `my_func` anywhere in `some_func()`, is it really a problem ?

Note: I cannot use `std::thread` or `boost::thread` unfortunately. I wish I could.

Comment: I'm no expert, but do nested scopes create new stack-frames for variables? Won't they be placed on the normal function stack frame? And if that's the case, then when will the destructor be called for objects inside nested scopes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: at the end of the nested scope.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: No, AFAIK they don't create a new stack frame, but the destructor will be called right after the call to `CreateThread()` in this example (this is required).  If the `std::function<>` implementation is not nice, it doesn't clean up after itself and this still works, but in a real program, this is highly likely to break.

Comment: +1, this is a cool question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it gets destroyed before `func()` happens, then you're calling a member function on an invalid object. You need to make a copy that will live at least until `func()` call.

Comment: When you say "`func()` happens": do you mean the moment where `func()` is called, or the moment `func()` call returns ?

Comment: Generally, you need the copy to live until the call has finished.

Comment: @ereOn: When `func` is called, obviously. If it returns, it'd imply the call already succeeded.

Comment: Well, what I meant was: considering `func` points to a **valid** object at the time of the call, what happens if `*func` gets destroyed **while** `func()` is still being executed ?

Comment: @ereOn: Well, dunno. Depends on what `std::function` does internally. I'd err on the safe side and keep the object alive until it returns, like @jpalecek suggested.

Comment: ereOn: the only *standardized* way that could happen is if you pass (a pointer to) the instance of func to the functor and delete it from within that function. Then you need to be careful to not touch any struct members or call any other struct functions, otherwise this should work IMHO. This is in the single-thread case. For multithreads, just use mutexes or other thread sync constructs.

Answer (score 2):

This is most certainly UB. Your comment is incorrect, there is nothing that will guarantee that `operator()` is called before the local is destroyed. In fact, I would consider it quite likely that it is destroyed before the new thread begins execution. Do this instead:

```
typedef std::function<void ()> func_type;

void some_func()
{
  // Irrelevant stuff here. Might take some time...
}

DWORD WINAPI thread_proc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
  func_type* func = static_cast<func_type*>(lpParameter);

  (*func)();

  delete func;

  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  HANDLE handle;

  {
    func_type* my_func = new func_type(some_func);

    handle = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, &thread_proc, my_func, 0, NULL);
  }

  ::WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know my comment is incorrect: That's why I commmented. My wording might be a bit off. What I meant is that in my real code I have a mechanism to prevent this. I just wonder about the case where the functor object is deleted *while* being called.

Comment: On most systems it probably works fine, but I don;t think there are any guarantees in the standard about this.